# Which between "I Most Love" or "What I Love The Most" is correct?

Tags: adjective-degrees

I'm rewriting a TV show's trailer script that was directly translated from Spanish. So I only had to make it grammatically sound if possible.

For the most part, it's alright but there's one part in one line where I'm not sure if it sounds quite okay when said:

"My sin is that I didn't have the courage to defend **what I most love**".

Should I left this part as is or should I amend it with "what I love the most".

It's for a TV show so the sentence is intended to be obscure.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that *what I most love* is idiomatically uncommon. As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+I+most+love%2Cwhat+I+love+most%2Cwhat+I+most+like%2Cwhat+I+like+most&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows, we normally put "most" *after* the verb, not *between* the subject and verb. This is probably at least partly influenced by the fact that we can only usually say *What I **like best** is X* (*What I **best like** is X* is completely unacceptable to most native speakers).

Answer (score 1):

"My sin is that I didn't have the courage to defend **what I love the most**" is correct.

Comment: **What I most love** is equally correct and sounds more dramatic. Take your choice. Equally, **the person I most love** and **the person I love the most**.. Both are perfectly acceptable but you might find that the choice depended on qualities such as the metre that best fitted the context..

Comment: +1, and what Ronald says, and you can also drop the "the": "*...to defend **what I love most***."